# Is this website protected against scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** annuary from this website :
http://www.presanse.fr/CISME/annuaire.aspx
In order to show you the informations i need to **scrape** please click on "tous les services" then a list will show, then click on a item (ex AST-BTP) and a page will show with a lot of informations ( i need all of them).
I try to check the code and i notice that there are <"div",class="ficheCorneeDetails"> that contains this informations, but i can't **scrape** it, my script return 'None'
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should use a headless browser like selenium.

Comment: ok thank you i will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you want is loaded using a JavaScript script, simply making the request using a scraper will not work.

You will need to emulate a click on the button using something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this as mentioned you need to utalize selenium in addition to Beautiful soup.

1) Download the geckoDriver (fire fox) here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

2) Extract the exe and add it to your system path

3) Install selenium with **pip install selenium**

4) Run the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.presanse.fr/CISME/annuaire.aspx')


availbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphMiddle_UC_RechercheParCarte1_linkTousLesServices')
availbutton.click()
time.sleep(2)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

targetDiv = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "resultatTable"})
targetsoup = BeautifulSoup(str(targetDiv),'lxml')
for span in targetsoup:
    print(span.text)

driver.close()
```

You can interact with elements that were before dynamically created, also you can click on DOM elements by using button.click(). I added the 2 second delay to allow the table to load as I was initally still getting blanks without allowing time for it to load!

Comment: Thank you for your answers, in order to scrap informations included into each page, i use a button.click() but the text will not show in the "span" tags.                                      This is the code i add to your's :                                                              availbutton2 =  driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphMiddle_UC_RechercheParCarte1_UC_RechercheResultat1_rResultat_ctl00_pLigne')
availbutton2.click()
time.sleep(2)

targetecart = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ecart"})

print(targetecart[0])